# Symfony 1 trim all spaces of input fields

Tags: forms, symfony1, doctrine-1.2

I'm running an application with Symfony1/ Doctrine1. Is there a simple way to trim all spaces either end of single line input fields? I'm using largely default fields and default admin modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, all validators in symfony1.4 have a disabled `trim` option. You can enable it by passing it to `true`, see [here](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/validator/sfValidatorBase.class.php)